# Java - Heuristic Exception

Tags: java, transactions, distributed-transactions

Can anyone share how to generate or simulate HeuristicCommitException using Atomikos?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create your own implementation of `XAResource` (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/xa/XAResource.html) which you would enlist to the Atomikos global transaction. Then during commit (commit phase of 2PC) you leave a first resource to be committed and your XAResource goes as second in the row. Then your one throws, I think, `XAException.XA_HEURRB` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/transaction/xa/XAException.html#XA_HEURRB) (implementing `commit` method to throw it).

Comment: Thanks Chalda.. this seem too complicated for ... i am using JMockit try whether i am able to simulate it first

Comment: I think it could not be but depends. I'm used to Narayana (see https://github.com/jbosstm/quickstart/blob/master/ArjunaJTA/maven/src/main/java/TransactionManagerExample.java) I expect API usage will be similar.